# How to save matched string of regex in Expect/Interact?

Tags: regex, tcl, expect

I am expecting any pattern in a spawn process, example,

```
interact {

    -re {.*} {

     set command $matched_expression

     send $command
 }
```

In the above code $matched_expression must have the **matched string** of `-re`

I have to SAVE in a variable  what `-re {.*}` have matched. Is there any way to do this ?

Answer (score 2):

```
interact {
    -re {.*} {
         set command $expect_out(0,string)
         send $command
    }
```

This is documented in the [expect man page](http://man.cx/expect), in the section for the `expect` command (starting with the paragraph "Upon matching a pattern...").